# Как узнать домен изображения из JSON для разрешения использовать домен в </network-security-config>

Tags: android, json, сеть, kotlin

Мне нужно в XML @xml/network_security_config  добавить

Основной домен уже добавлен, отображается список в RecyclerView на эмуляторе, но не отображаются изображения.

В ответе JSON о изображении есть такая информация  "poster_path":"/xBHvZcjRiWyobQ9kxBhO6B2dtRI.jpg" , как узнать домен этого изображения?

Comment: изображения гружу с помощью Picasso,

Answer (score 0):

ОТВЕТ: Нужно было зайти в доку АПИ (в моем случае the movie DB , там был ответ относительно того, где хранятся изображения. Не удаляю вопрос, вдруг кому -то будет полезно